# Am I able to split up a large SEM model into smaller SEM models?

Tags: spss, structural-equation-modeling, amos

I have a SEM model in SPSS AMOS that is testing the mediating effect of information sharing on the relationship between the three dimensions of trustworthiness (which are ability, integrity and benevolence) and innovation. The picture below depicts my SEM model.

[image]

When I run the full structural model on SPSS AMOS, the results are not what I expected and almost all my hypothesises are not supported. However, when I split my large model into 3 smaller models to run my SEM analysis (as per below), most of the results support my hypothesises. Am I allowed to split my large model into 3 separate smaller models and under what conditions can I split a large model into smaller ones? Are there any downsides to splitting my larger model to a three smaller models, other than conducting 3 separate tests?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several good reasons to split up a larger structural equation model (SEM) into smaller ones (e.g., the full model is too complex for a given sample size). However, I would not say failure to support a hypothesis is one of these reasons. Of course, you are *allowed* to do whatever you want. If you do report results from the simpler models, I would also recommend including results from the larger model.

Finally, from the inspection of your path diagrams, your three smaller models seem to represent very different hypotheses. For instance, ability is an exogenous (independent) variable in your larger model, though it is an endogenous (dependent) variable in your three smaller models. See David Kenny's [Terminology and Basics of SEM](https://davidakenny.net/cm/basics.htm) article for more info on SEM terminology.

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake on my diagram, i have fixed it. My rationale to split the larger SEM model into smaller model is more so based on my hypothesis where I'm testing the dimensions of trustworthiness (the subconstruct) against innovation. If my hypothesis / research question was to answer how does trustworthiness (the main construct) fare against innovation, i would do a large SEM model.

Answer (score 1):

When you split the model into smaller models, you no longer account (or "statistically control") for the covariances (partial redundancy, overlap) among the exogeneous (independent) variables. It is therefore not surprising that the results differ. Also, your outcome variables (innovation vs. ability) seem to differ across the different models.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake on my diagram, fixed it now. Do you perhaps know of any literature that allows a larger model to be split up into smaller models?